# Windows 8.1 clients querying wrong ldap SRV record?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I just spotted than my PC, running Windows 8.1 Pro on a Windows 2012 R2 domain has been querying DNS for SRV records that doesn't exist.

All of the **dcdiag /dnsall** tests pass, but I wonder if there's something in Group Policy that is causing clients to query for the wrong SRV record.

When running **ipconfig /displaydns** to check the TTL on a cached DNS record, I spotted these:

```
_ldap._tcp.server1.contoso.com
----------------------------------------
Name does not exist.

_ldap._tcp.site-name._sites.server1.contoso.com
----------------------------------------
Name does not exist.
```

*(site name, domain and server name changed).*

For some reason, the DNS lookup includes the name of the logon server in the FQDN.  If it had looked up **_ldap._tcp.**<strike>server1.</strike>**contoso.com** and **_ldap._tcp.site-name._sites.**<strike>server1.</strike>**contoso.com**, they would have returned the right records.

Am I just being paranoid, or is there something wrong with the way I've got our Active Directory / DNS configured?

Comment: Interestingly, this question has been asked before IIRC and I saw this same behavior in my own lab and production environments. I don't think an answer was ever produced that explained the behavior but I'm going to go back and see if I can find the question to confirm that. If I find anything useful I'll post back here.

Comment: Found it. Here's the related question, but no definitive answer. - http://serverfault.com/questions/669884/windows-hosts-dns-query-for-ldap-tcp-domaincontroller-is-this-normal

Comment: Yep. I remember this. None of us ever figured it out. Wonder if it's a (relatively benign) bug.

Comment: I came across that question after I'd posted mine... it kinda looks like a bug in the OS, but like @KeithTwombley, I don't buy that this is "normal".